# Laravel index blade mostrar nombre de una foreign key

Tags: laravel

Quisiera saber cómo podría mostrar el nombre de la especialidad asignada a cada médico. Este es mi index blade actual de médico:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@include('layouts.menu')

<a href="createDoctor" class="btn btn-info">Registrar un nuevo médico</a>
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellidos</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Consulta</th>
<th>ID especialidad</th>
<th>Número de teléfono</th>
<th>Género</th>
<th>Administrador</th>
<th>Edición</th>
<th>Borrar médico</th>
  </thead>


   </tbody>
  @foreach ($doctors as $doctor) 

<tr>
<td>{{ $doctor->id}}</td>
<td>{{ $doctor->name}}</td>
<td>{{ $doctor->surnames}}</td>
<td>{{ $doctor->email}}</td>
<td>{{ $doctor->room}}</td>

<td>{{ $doctor->speciality_id}}</td>

<td>{{ $doctor->phone}}</td>
<td>{{ $doctor->gender}}</td>
<td>{{ $doctor->admin}}</td>
<td>
  <a href="editDoctor?id={{ $doctor->id}}" class="btn btn-info">Editar médico</a>
   </td>
    <td>
     <a href="deleteDoctor?id={{ $doctor->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>

     </td>

      </tr>

     @endforeach
     </tbody>
     </table>



          @endsection
```

Y el método index de su controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $specialities = Speciality::all();
    $doctors = DB::table('users')
      ->join('doctors', 'users.id','doctors.user_id')
      ->select('users.*','doctors.*')
      ->get();


    return view('doctors/index')->with('doctors',$doctors)->with('specialities',$specialities);

       }
```

Entonces probé a añadir esto en la index blade:

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
@foreach ($specialities as $speciality)
<tr>
<td> {{$doctor->id}}</td>
 ......
```

Con esto logré mostrar el nombre de la especialidad pero no de la forma esperada. Entonces probé a escribir simplemente `<td>{{doctor->speciality->name}}</td>`pero no funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo vas a hacer de esa forma entonces debes de imprimir la especialidad cuando sea la que pertenece al respectivo médico, esto lo haces comparando el `id` del doctor con el `id_doctor` que debes tener en la tabla especialidades:

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
<tr>
<td>
    @foreach ($specialities as $speciality)
        @if($doctor->id == $speciality->doctor_id)
            {{ $speciality->name }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
</td>
 ......
```

De esta forma te aseguras que se imprima la especialidad que corresponde a cada doctor.

Otra forma en la que se podría hacer es desde la misma consulta traer la especialidad de cada doctor por medio de un `join`, así evitar tener que cargar todas las especialidades y luego tener que recorrerlas:

```
public function index()
{
    $doctors = DB::table('users')
      ->join('doctors', 'users.id','doctors.user_id')
      ->join('specialitys', 'users.id','specialitys.doctor_id')
      ->select('users.*','doctors.*','specialitys.name as speciality')
      ->get();

    return view('doctors/index')->with('doctors',$doctors);

}
```

Para luego mostrar en la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
<tr>
<td>
    {{ $doctor->speciality }}
</td>
 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Con Eloquent puedes lograrlo usando una relación belongsTo. Te sugiero lo siguiente:

Crear un model Doctor (si no lo tienes), en el cual tendrás un método así:

```
public function speciality()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Speciality', 'speciality_id', 'id');
}
```

Luego modifica tu consulta en tu controller:

```
$doctors = DB::table('users')
      ->join('doctors', 'users.id','doctors.user_id')
      ->select('users.*','doctors.*')
      ->get();
```

Por:

```
$doctors = App\Doctor::join('doctors', 'users.id','doctors.user_id')
                 ->select('users.*','doctors.*')
                 ->get();
```

Y en tu vista pues recorres la colección de doctors (como lo vienes haciendo), y solo necesitas acceder a la especialidad como lo deseas:

```
{{ $doctor->speciality->name }}
```

Si necesitas más info sobre cómo usar relaciones con Eloquent, puedes guiarte por la documentación oficial de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse